# If angle is not a closed figure, then how does it contain interior points? We know that every closed figure contains interior points.

Tags: geometry, angle

I came across this in my book that"The portion common to both shadings is
called the interior of ∠ABC" and i also have read that "In a closed curve, there are three parts.
(i) interior (‘inside’) of the curve
(ii) boundary (‘on’) of the curve and
(iii) exterior (‘outside’) of the curve"
but, If angle is not a closed figure, then how does it contain interior points?

Thanks for replying, yea true i was reading and i get confused as
 1.) why angles not being a closed curve have interior parts,
2.) what if the angle is 180 degree which part is exterior and which is interior.Considering an angle 60 degree its interior part is the area common to the sides but
 3.) what about 150 degree interior part ? can we still say the same common area under to both the sides. Is this true? .
 4.) One more thing does the points on the boundary of the angle(basically rays) and on the origin(0,0) are also included in interior point of that angle? My opinion is if placed on coordinate axes the horizontal ray will look like (x,0) and vertical ray(assuming 90 degree angle) (y,0) so boundary points are interior points and point on origin is exterior. i am confused Please correct me if i am wrong
[image][image]

Comment: To say "A closed curve has an interior," is not the same as saying, "Anything that is not a closed curve has no interior."

Comment: Don't compare it with a closed curve. Closed curves have interior, exterior and boundary but that doesn't mean they are the *only* things with interior, exterior and boundary.  The thing is the rays of the the angle are unbounded and infinite so the points in the 'interior" can be isolated from those in the "exterior" with the only way to connect them is to cross a ray.

Comment: A university has a deans office, classrooms, and libraries.  A city has parks, theaters, and libraries.  But how can a city have libraries if it's not a university?

Comment: You forgot to remove the "not to be republished" warning when you (essentially) republished this.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yea true i was reading and i get confused. One more thing does the points on the boundary of the angle(basically rays) and on the origin(0,0) are also included in interior point of that angle? My opinion is if placed on coordinate axes the horizontal ray will look like (x,0) and vertical ray(assuming 90 degree angle) (y,0) so boundary points are interior points and point on origin is exterior.Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Dave L. Renfro, how to remove it, its pdf and i am not using it to earn money, is this a problem? for this site?

Comment: Don't worry about it, I'm just kidding! I should have put :) at the end. As for your question, often the same word is used in one area of math for something entirely different (or for something just slightly different) in another area of math. This can certainly cause confusion when you're first learning something.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks for replying, yea true i was reading and i get confused. One more thing does the points on the boundary of the angle(basically rays) and on the origin(0,0) are also included in interior point of that angle? My opinion is if placed on coordinate axes the horizontal ray will look like (x,0) and vertical ray(assuming 90 degree angle) (y,0) so boundary points are interior points and point on origin is exterior. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @whoami : The vertex of the angle (the origin in your example) is point $Q$ in the fourth row in the image.  All of $P$, $Q$, $R$, and $S$ are neither interior nor exterior to the angle.  All four are described "on the [angle]".

Comment: I'm not loving the text.  But it says shade the region *boardering* on BA which implies not including BA.  So the interior does not include the rays or the vertex.  The exterior does not include the rays of the vertex, and the angle itself what the text calls "on the angle" (not loving it) and is it's own boundary (as a curveis its own boundary) is the rays and the vertex.  ... Please don't think too hard about it. Closed curves and angles have interiors, exteriors and boundaries. Just like you'd think they'd be.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for the patience reply, one more time pls you seem to say that the book is wrong, does this mean that point S should not be called on the angle and does this mean that either of interior or exterior parts of angle should include the rays and vertex which part is that? and not focusing on the text, in reality, what if the angle is 180 deg which part is exterior and which is interior.Considering an angle 60 degree its interior part is the area common to the sides but what about 150 degree interior part ?can we still say the same common area under to both the sides.Is this true?

Comment: I didn't say the boook was wrong.  I said I didn't love it.  I don't think it's clear.  But it's not wrong.

Comment: @fleablood you didn't love it, is it because a point has no length, breadth, it is just a representation of location and a line has only one dimension length, line has no breadth ? i will be very thankful if you would like to share the more clear approach to this topic.

Comment: @saulspatz thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The quoted passage

> In a closed curve, there are three parts. (i) interior (‘inside’) of the curve (ii) boundary (‘on’) of the curve and (iii) exterior (‘outside’) of the curve.

describes the "interior points" of a closed curve.  It does not provide any guidance for things which are not closed curves.  You observe that an angle is not a closed curve.  Therefore, the definition above provides no guidance about interior points of an angle.

A less abstract parallel may be helpful.  We are told that "time flies like an arrow."  Does this provide any guidance on how fruit flies?  (... with apologies to [E.B. Oettinger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_flies_like_an_arrow;_fruit_flies_like_a_banana).)

Actually, since the description of closed curves does not give guidance on interior points of an angle, you have to be told explicitly which points of an angle are interior points, which is what the image you have included is doing.

Comment: I also note that the OP cites something about "a closed curve" and then says an angle is not "a closed figure". This makes the entire question something like saying a rabbit has a head, so how can a rock, which is not an apple, have a head?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro : I'm inclined to give OP the benefit of the doubt:  In particular, that "closed curve" has been defined as a "closed figure".  Although I could be wrong, it does not change this Answer.

Comment: FYI, I'm in the middle of my day (contract) job of editing certain high-stakes quant test items, so my radar for things such as this is turned on high right now!

Comment: @EricTowers yea true i am confused as why angles not being a closed curve have interior parts, what if the angle is 180 degree which part is exterior and which is interior.Considering an angle 60 degree its interior part is the area common to the sides but what about 150 degree interior part ? can we still say the same common area under to both the sides. Is this true?

Comment: The instructions given in your image lead to the result that a straight angle has no interior points because there is no "portion of the paper ... where [the other ray] lies."  However, for any non-straight angle, there is no ambiguity -- only the "narrow" part of the angle is the interior , the part having angle measure 60 degrees and the part having angle measure 150 degrees in your examples.  The parts having measures 300 degrees and 210 degrees do not contain interior points and in both cases are not the "portion of the paper ... where [the other ray] lies."

Comment: @EricTowers thanks!